# why cant I save data to database?

Tags: vue.js, axios

Trying to insert form data by this function.

Here is my function:

```
saveTimeline() {
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("title", this.title);
      formData.append("from", this.from);
      formData.append("to", this.to);
      formData.append("events[0].year", this.year);
      formData.append("events[0].image", this.softCopyUpload);
      formData.append("events[0].content", this.content);
      formData.append("events[0].audio", this.audioFile);
      console.log(formData);
      this.$axios
        .post(this.$API + "api/v1/admin/timelines/", formData, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
          },
        })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res) {
            console.log("success");
          }
        });
    },
```

Error: "Timeline title must not be set to empty"

Always getting this error. Why ?

Why append is not working ?

**My JSON**

```
{
    "title": "dvdvds",
    "from": 1990,
    "to": 2010,
    "events": [
        {
            "year": 1990,
            "image": "test.jpg",
            "content": "test content",
            "audio": "test.mp4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way to upload file without using formData.append()  ?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what kind of object "this" is, but are you sure that this.title has been set to something, and is not empty?

Comment: yes. its not empty.

Comment: I have inserted data without using append. But as I have to upload file thats why I am using append. But its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't set the form data correctly. The docs suggest [something like this](https://axios-http.com/docs/urlencoded) for the browser:

```
const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('param1', 'value1');
params.append('param2', 'value2');
axios.post('/foo', params);
```

Comment: Used params. The first three data are not giving any error now. Now the fourth data is giving error saying  "Timeline event year must not be set to empty"

Comment: That's most likely because `URLSearchParams` won't serialize objects. Example:

`const foo = new URLSearchParams();  foo.append("bar", {foo: "foo", bar:"bar"});  foo.toString()` returns ` "bar=%5Bobject+Object%5D"`

Are you sure your the keys you use to `append` are formatted correctly? Also: Do you really have to submit your data as form data? Is `application/json` not supported? That would be much easier.

Comment: Yes using application/json its working. I think append is not supported in that project. I dont know why.